# When solving the wave equation by separation of variables, has the separation constant a special meaning?

Tags: waves, differential-equations

When we solve the wave equation using the method of separation of variables (for instance, in one dimension),

$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$  ;  $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$  ⟹  $\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda$

does this constant of separation , $\lambda$, have a special meaning? I see that, if $c$ is the propagation velocity of the wave in the medium, it has units of $meter^{-2}$... Does it have something to do with the wavenumber, $k$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you calculate the solution $$u(x,t)=[c_1 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)+c_2 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x)][c_3 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} t)+c_4 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} t)]$$ you see that $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is the wavenumber.

$\lambda$ on its own is not so interesting, it is just a free parameter that here gives you a wavenumber. But suppose there was a boundary condition like $u(0,t)=0$ and $u(1,t)=0$ for all $t$. Then only some values of $\lambda$ are possible, and they set the frequencies in time too. When you do boundary value problems these possible values of the constants of separation are known as eigenvalues and they tend to be important.

Answer (score 0):

The separation constant $\lambda$  corresponds to the wavenumbers $$k=±\sqrt {\lambda}=\frac {\omega}{c}$$ of the wave solutions $$u=u_0 \exp{i(kx-\omega t)}$$